# NHibernate Sqlite3 db Could not add assembly hibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite

Could not add assembly hibernate in visual studio 2012 nhibernate I'm getting this error

cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2"  >
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Data Source=SicakSatisDB.db;Version=3;
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: specify and detail the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

```
cfg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2"  >
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Data Source=SicakSatisDB.db;Version=3;
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hmb.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<hibernate-mapping assembly="hibernate" namespace="Domain" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Stokkartitbl" table="StokKartiTbl" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Id" column="ID" />
    <property name="Stokkodu">
      <column name="StokKodu" type="nchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Stokadi1">
      <column name="StokAdi1" type="nvarchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Stokadi2">
      <column name="StokAdi2" type="nvarchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Birim">
      <column name="Birim" type="int" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Satisfiyati">
      <column name="SatisFiyati" type="money" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Alisfiyati">
      <column name="AlisFiyati" type="money" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Aliskdvid">
      <column name="AlisKDVID" type="int" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Satiskdvid">
      <column name="SatisKDVID" type="int" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Grupid">
      <column name="GrupID" type="int" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="Reyonid">
      <column name="ReyonID" type="int" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>
```